# Regex for finding substrings using Grep Console in Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

I am using Grep Console in Eclipse to highlight lines in the console output that contain characters, e.g. `cancel`, based on a regex. The characters may have a symbol preceding and/or following it, may be surrounded by spaces, or may be substrings. In other words, I want to match the following lines (regardless of case):

```
 The flight was cancelled.
 [Cancelled] Flight 101
 Are they going to cancel it?
```

What is the regex that I need to use to highlight these lines?

Answer (score 2):

As acdcjunior already explained, you basically just need a case insensitive regular expression to match "cancel".

If you already have your output in the console, the easiest way to create this expression is to just select the word "cancel" in the output, then right click and select "Add Expression" from the context menu. A submenu will you select a group to which the new expression will be added, or create a new one. The expression item will then be created, using the following expression:

```
(\Qcancel\E)
```

Be sure to uncheck the "Case sensitive" checkbox, which is enabled by default for performance reasons and would prevent the expression from matching your second line with the capital 'C'.

This is basically the same expression acdcjunior provided, with a few differences:

The `.*` matchers at the beginning and end of the expression are not included, as they are not necessary. Expressions will always match substrings anywhere in a line unless the `$` or `^` matchers are used to specifically refer to the beginning or end of a line.

The expression is also wrapped in parentheses to create a capture group, allowing you to assign a style not only to the entire line containing the string `cancel`, but also to that string itself. You can leave out the parentheses if you don't want to style that string.

`\Q` and `\E` are always included when creating an expression from a selected text string to make sure that no characters from the selected string are interpreted as special expression characters. In this case, this not necessary, as `cancel` only contains word characters.

This means that in your case, the simplest sufficient expression is just:

```
cancel
```

This expression also works if you use it as a "quick expression", as suggested by acdcjunior, though there is no real need for this. The idea behind quick expressions is that very long lines in the console can considerably slow down pattern matching. Grep Console therefore has a configurable limit to how many characters in each line will be matched with the configured expressions. Any characters after this limit in long lines are ignored, which means that lines which contain keywords only after the limit will not be recognised and therefore not styled.

If you configure a quick expression, every line is first matched with this expression, and only if the match is positive will the "normal" expression be used. In this case, the expressions are matched against *the entire line*. The quick expression should therefore be as simple as possible, so as not to slow down the matching too much.

In your case, using `cancel` as a quick expression and leaving the normal expression blank works because first the quick expression is positively matched against your line, and then the blank expression matches as well. If you have very long lines, it may cost you some performance though, as the quick expression will ignore the length limits explained above. Also, quick expression don't use capture groups, so you can't highlight the `cancel` string with a separate style in this case.

Comment: Chiming in: I added an expression to match the verbose lines of JVM: `^(\[Loaded .*\])$`. I am weirdly getting the match on random lines (within the lines that match the regex): some gets styled, some other not. Any idea? Is this happening to me only? PS Same thing removing `^$` line delimiters.  U_U

Comment: Could it be related to the quick expressions and line length limits described above? I.e., are the lines that are not matched perhaps longer than the configured limits?
I imagine that the group you specify means that the expression has to match the entire line, so if the line is too long, it may cause problems.
(If you want to highlight the entire line anyway, you can also just leave out the group: `^\[Loaded .*\]$` and apply the style to the entire line)

Comment: Nope.. I have not defined any quick expression and I get the same behaviour leaving out the grouping. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
.*(\Qcancel\E).*
```

And do not check "Case sensitive".

Or just `cancel` in the "Quick expression" text box.

Comment: I did some tests here and both worked. So let me know if they work for you as well.